# How can a C program tell if it was launched from the Finder?

Tags: c, macos, directory, program-entry-point, finder

The title kind of says it all:

I'm wondering if there's any `_NSWasLaunchedFromFinder`-type API or hook that an OS/X C program (of the `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` variety) could use to determine if it was launched by a user clicking on the executable in the Finder vs. if it was run through a more traditional route (like being typed into the Terminal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about plain command line utility - there is no way to determine whether it was launched from Finder or in terminal since Finder will launch terminal and then execute your program in it.
But there is a solution. I'd rather call it a workaround. You can wrap your executable with bundle, create simple script (lets call it `finderLauncher`) which will launch actual executable with some additional command line parameter (`-launchedFromFinder` for example). Don't forget to make it executable. Than in your Info.plist file set `finderLauncher` as `CFBundleExecutable` value.
And now in Finder user will see only your bundle and by clicking on it your actual executable will be launched via `finderLauncher` passing specified command line parameter. Same behaviour will be by using `open` command in terminal.

And by direct launch from terminal there would be no -launchedFromFinder parameter (off course if user will not pass it directly).

P.s. It would be much easier by specifying command line parameters directly in Info.plist, but I can't find such key in [Information Property List Key Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Introduction/Introduction.html) although there is such key for agents/daemons.

Comment: Thanks...that's an interesting idea with the bundle; although may not be good for this purpose.  Still I imagine no particular trickery would be needed then...as bundled programs generally assume they were launched from the Finder?  Is there a way for a bundled executable to just ask what directory it was launched in without going through any hoops like the workaround you suggest?

Comment: It is not a 'bundled executable', it is still the same executable. Bundle just says Finder to use `open` on this directory. `open` reads Info.plist and launch executable specified in CFBundleExecutable. Thats it. So all directories will be the same as in terminal. So any directory-determination magic wouldn't be of much help.

Comment: There is another thing: usually when app launched by `open` - it gets passed so called process serial number as argument which looks like `-psn_blablabla`. But I don't think it is a good idea to rely on that parameter - looks like it is for some internal use and as far as I remember not all processes have a PSN passed.

Comment: I agree with @cody here. I did some research trawling the ADC references, and found nothing. I also wrote a test app that dumps out all the environment variables and all command line data (including the little-known `apple` parameter).  I also analysed the process hierarchy, and Finder is not the parent process.  Given the way in which the binary is spawned, there really doesn't appear to be any way to distinguish the launching method.  I think the hybrid approach described by @cody above is a good idea, and will allow you much more explicit control.

Comment: I actually wandered off working on other things, but the bounty needs to be awarded at some point despite my distractedness.  :-)  Thanks to everyone, actually, for the good input.  At the end of the day I don't know if sensitivity to launch source is worth the added complexity...I look at such workarounds with skepticism and like to [K.I.S.S.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) as they say...but I'll come back to this question when I get back to worrying about the deployment of the [Rebol Binaries](http://rebolsource.net/)!

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1 ::** 
You can use NSGetExecutablePath

Here's the dev reference to it :: [Mac Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dyld.3.html)

_NSGetExecutablePath() copies the path of the main executable into the buffer buf.  The bufsize parameter should initially be the size of the buffer.  This function returns 0 if the path was successfully copied, and  * bufsize is left unchanged.  It returns -1 if the buffer is not large enough, and *
     bufsize is set to the size required.  Note that _NSGetExecutablePath() will return "a path" to the exe-
     cutable not a "real path" to the executable.  That is, the path may be a symbolic link and not the real
     file. With deep directories the total bufsize needed could be more than MAXPATHLEN.

**Method 2 ::** 
Use AppleScript

You can use AppleScript to find the current applications open with the following script ::

```
tell application "Finder"
set appPath to my getFrontAppPath()
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {":"}
set currentApp to text item -2 of appPath
say currentApp
end tell

on getFrontAppPath()
    set frontAppPath to (path to frontmost application) as text
    set myPath to (path to me) as text

    if frontAppPath is myPath then
        try
            tell application "Finder" to set bundleID to id of file myPath
            tell application "System Events" to set visible of (first process whose bundle identifier is bundleID) to false

            -- we need to delay because it takes time for the process to hide
            -- I noticed this when running the code as an application from the applescript menu bar item
            set inTime to current date
            repeat
                set frontAppPath to (path to frontmost application) as text
                if frontAppPath is not myPath then exit repeat
                if (current date) - inTime is greater than 2 then exit repeat
            end repeat
        end try
    end if
    return frontAppPath
end getFrontAppPath
```

That should get you the application last opened, whether it was Terminal or Finder :)

For Finder you get a response :: "Macintosh HD:System:Library:CoreServices:Finder.app:"

For Terminal :: "Macintosh HD:Applications:Utilities:Terminal.app:"

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  But unfortunately terminal programs launched from the Finder always start up with a notion of the active directory being the user's root home directory, and from the terminal they will start up in the directory you run them from (even if the actual executable is in, say, `/usr/bin`).  I wanted to retain the Terminal-launch behavior but then if launched from the Finder in a specific directory to use `NSGetExecutablePath`...which I already knew about.  I cannot make that distinction in behavior if I don't know if it was launched from the Finder or not.  :-/

Comment: Couldn't you assume, that if the user's root home directory comes up, then the app has been launched from Terminal ? By simple elimination ?

Comment: I think you mean Finder, but I catch your drift.  That's an interesting idea, but that sort of trick that works only *most* of the time often leads to fragile and/or hack-exploitable systems.  There's going to be that one day that someone puts the executable in `/usr/bin` and then runs from their home directory, and absent-mindedly thinks *"oh, I don't need the files in my home directory that aren't directories, `>> delete * from current dir`"* and then `/usr/bin` goes poof!!  :-/

Comment: Ok, I added in a second option to the code. Using the appleScript I've added in above, you can find out the last application open, whether Terminal or Finder. Just tried it, it seems to work fine :)

Answer (score 0):

[Get the Parent Process ID](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/getpid.2.html). Then browse its [Process Status](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/ps.1.html) to get its PPID, recursively up to Finder.app or [init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init).

Once you have found the terminal ancestor that is child of Finder.app, you can look at its start time and its arguments (see the `-o` and `-O` options in `man ps`: your keywords should include `args` and `start`): if the terminal process started near your programm start time and the arguments include your program name, you know that it has been started by Finder.app.

Probably, you can ignore the times and just look for the terminal's arguments.

Comment: I don't think it will help. If you will launch utility from finder - it will do it using terminal. And in other case you can launch terminal from finder and then launch utility from there. In both cases same chain: Finder - Terminal - Binary

Comment: @cody obviously, with ps he can look at the terminal process start time and compare it with its own. moreover he can check if the terminal has other children. finally with proper options, he can check the terminal arguments to verify the presence of his own program.

Comment: I verified this - the process hierarchy is no different between the user launching it in Terminal and launching from Finder.  And the Finder process is _not_ the parent.  It uses RPC (AppleScript I believe) to invoke the binary, which means Terminal is launching it exactly the way the user would.  The arguments are identical in either case AFAICT.  Not sure how timestamps would help - sounds fragile.

Comment: RPC to invoke a binary? Sound strange. What's the other endpoint of the RPC from Finder.app?

Answer (score 0):

You can assume the reverse logic and use isatty.

```
if (isatty(1)) printf("Launched in a terminal\n");
else printf("Launched by clicking something\n");
```

This just determines if stdout is a tty.  If you launch it from a program, icon, menu etc... it will be false.  also if you want to tell if an X server is running and it was launched from a terminal emulator you can use getenv("DISPLAY") which is set when X starts (so it will be NULL if run from the console)

Comment: I like it, 90% accurate solution, there is no reason to work for hours on the remaining 10%. Tested on Linux (GNome, Nautilus).

Comment: The question states the environment is Mac OS X, so the above won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // when the user doubleclicks your program it will be started with a -psn_ parameter
    if (argc >= 2 && (strncmp(argv[1], "-psn_", 5) == 0)) {
        InfoLogWithClient(L"Init", L"Program %d cannot be started with double-click!", getpid());
        return EX_USAGE;
    }
```

Comment: Not true anymore on macOS Sierra apparently (well not always true anyway…)